# Autosize = uniform only shrinks text to fit, not increasing size

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView that sometimes contains a short string sometimes a long one, I need its font to resize to it's best fit. This works well when it comes to shrinking. I'm not sure why but once the textView font size is shrinked, it stays that size when the TextView is updated with a setText, even if the string is really short. So basically, autosize=uniform is being able to shrink to its best fit, but not to grow to its best fit. What am I missing?

```
           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preguntaView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/verticalLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase your `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize`.

```
android:textSize="24sp"
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="24sp"
```

You have set the `textSize` and `autoSizeMaxTextSize` to the same value which means that the text is only able to shrink, as it can't get any bigger than `24sp`. To fix this increase the `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize`.

You could also try using a fixed value for the height of the `TextView`.

Comment: I changed that but no difference. The problem is that the text might go down to 10sp in a long string, but it will never increase more than 10sp once it is resized.

Comment: You could try using a fixed value for the height of the `TextView`

Comment: Great to hear :-)